# Multiple Marshal badges?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

As far as I can tell, [I was awarded the Marshal badge just once](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/badges/84/marshal), a few months ago. When I logged in to MY tonight, I was told that I had received it another two times on Mi Yodeya:

> [image: picture of the Stack Exchange Super-Collider expanded, showing a few reputation changes, and "You've earned the Marshal badge" etc twice]

I'm pretty sure that this is a bug; I don't think that Marshal is meant to be awarded more than once (and anyways, I don't have enough helpful flags for more than one).

Comment: [This has been fixed](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/280023), so I'm marking this question as [meta-tag:status-completed]. (You're seeing a notification from before it was fixed, but you have the correct number of badges listed at your profile.)

Comment: @msh210 All right, then.